# C# equivalent of Java snippet for Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, ormlite, sqlite-net

I am trying to convert Android code base which is using ORMLite to its C# equivalent for Xamarin.Android which uses  SQLite-net PCL nuget package.

Java :

```
public abstract class DTAbstractEntity {


}

import entities.DTAbstractEntity;
import com.j256.ormlite.field.DatabaseField;

public abstract class DTAbstractModelEntity<T extends DTAbstractEntity> extends DTAbstractEntity {

    public final static String ID_FIELD_NAME = "uuid";

    @DatabaseField(id = true, canBeNull = false, columnName = ID_FIELD_NAME)
    protected String uuid;

    @DatabaseField
    protected String name;

    @DatabaseField
    protected String path;

    @DatabaseField
    protected boolean completeResponse;

    /* GETTERS */
    public String getUuid() { return uuid; }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public boolean isCompleteResponse() {
        return completeResponse;
    }
}

import com.j256.ormlite.field.DatabaseField;
import com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTable;

@DatabaseTable
public class DTProfile extends DTAbstractModelEntity {

    @DatabaseField
    private int unreadCount;

    @DatabaseField
    private boolean linkedInAuthorised;

    @DatabaseField
    private boolean hasSubscriptions;

    @DatabaseField(foreign=true, foreignAutoCreate = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
    private DTLocale localePreference;

    @DatabaseField
    private String loginType;  //email or social login provider ie twitter, google, facebook etc

    /* CONSTRUCTOR */
    public DTProfile() {
        //constructor stub - needed by ORMLite
    }

     /* GETTERS */

    public int getUnreadCount() {
        return unreadCount;
    }

    public boolean isLinkedInAuthorised() {
        return linkedInAuthorised;
    }

    public boolean isHasSubscriptions() {
        return hasSubscriptions;
    }

    public DTLocale getLocalePreference() {
        return localePreference;
    }

    public String getLoginType() { return loginType; }

}
```

Can anyone provide their guidance here to migrate the Java code to its C# equivalent

Answer (score 0):

I checked your last question: [What is the equivalent package of ORMLite used in case of Xamarin.Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/users/830972/santosh-kumar-patro), the answer there suggested to use `SQLite` instead of `OrmLite`, but you didn't mark that answer, so I guess that you don't want to replace this `OrmLite` package.

Then, you can use `Binding Library` of Xamarin to create a Xamarin.Android Java Bindings Library for Xamarin.Android from an Android .JAR file.

I tested to download the [OrmLite android 5.0 jar package](http://ormlite.com/releases/) and followed the [official guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-a-jar/) here to create a dll, works fine.

[image]

[image]

If you want to know how to use `SQLite-net PCL`, you may check this: [Create a Database with SQLite](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/databases/sqlite/), your code looks like only for creating tables in database, this doc also provide sample for creating, connecting database and insert, get data from database. Here is the [sample code](https://github.com/xamarin/recipes/tree/master/android/data/databases/sqlite).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I accepted the answer to my previous question:  What is the equivalent package of ORMLite used in case of Xamarin.Android application :)

Comment: @santoshkumarpatro, OK, then have you checked doc and sample I provided in the end of my answer for `SQLite-net PCL`, is that not helpful?

Comment: I am trying that sample. Thanks for the links :)